# Fine-Tune pre-trained InceptionResnetV2

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, keras

Steps for fine-tuning a network are as follow:

1. Add your custom network on top of an already trained base
   network.
2. Freeze the base network.
3. Train the part you added.
4. Unfreeze some layers in the base network.
5. Jointly train both these layers and the part you added.

Now if the network architecture is simple as VGG16, we can simply unfreeze the base network from `block5_conv1 (Conv2D)` and re-train it.

**VGG16 Architecture**
[image: VGG16 Architecture]

But When the architecture is highly complex as InceptionResnetV2, where to start? Does anyone has any practical experience? Run the following code in python to see the model:

```
from keras.applications import InceptionResNetV2

conv_base = InceptionResNetV2(weights='imagenet',
                  include_top=False,
                  input_shape=(299, 299, 3))
conv_base.summary()
from keras.utils import plot_model
plot_model(conv_base, to_file='model.png')`
```

Answer (score 1):

A very basic fine-tuning of model with InceptionResNetV2 will look like this:

```
from inception_resnet_v2 import InceptionResNetV2
# ImageNet classification

model = InceptionResNetV2()
model.predict(...)

# Finetuning on another 100-class dataset
base_model = InceptionResNetV2(include_top=False, pooling='avg')
# The first argument in the next line represents the number of classes
outputs = Dense(100, activation='softmax')(base_model.output)
model = Model(base_model.inputs, outputs)
model.compile(...)
model.fit(...)
```

This is a good place to start [github.com/yuyang-huang/keras-inception-resnet-v2](https://github.com/yuyang-huang/keras-inception-resnet-v2/blob/master/README.md)